# How to delete the margin around SmartFilterBar?

Tags: sapui5

I have `SmartFilterBar` inside a `SplitPane` that looks as following:

[image]

and I would like to delete the spaces around the `SmartFilterBar`.

The code for the view:

```
<l:SplitPane requiredParentWidth="400" demandPane="true" id="default">
    <Panel height="100%">
        <smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar id="smartFilterBar" entitySet="ZMM_C_CLASSIFICATION" search="_onSearch">
            <smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>
                <smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration key="ClassType" visibleInAdvancedArea="true" preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="false"></smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
                <smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration key="ClassNum" visibleInAdvancedArea="true" preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="false"></smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
            </smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>
        </smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar>
        <Tree id="classTree" items="{path: 'Tree>/'}" toggleOpenState="onToggleOpenState">
            <CustomTreeItem>
                <FlexBox width="100%" alignItems="Center" justifyContent="SpaceBetween">
                    <items>
                        <Label text="{Tree>text}" wrapping="true"/>
                        <Button icon="sap-icon://display" type="Transparent" press="onItemPress"/>
                    </items>
                </FlexBox>
            </CustomTreeItem>
        </Tree>
    </Panel>
    <l:layoutData>
        <l:SplitterLayoutData size="30%"/>
    </l:layoutData>
</l:SplitPane>
```

**Update**

I also tried:

```
<l:SplitPane requiredParentWidth="400" demandPane="true" id="default">
    <l:content>
        <smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar id="smartFilterBar" entitySet="ZMM_C_CLASSIFICATION" search="_onSearch">
            <smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>
                <smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration key="ClassType" visibleInAdvancedArea="true" preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="false"></smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
                <smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration key="ClassNum" visibleInAdvancedArea="true" preventInitialDataFetchInValueHelpDialog="false"></smartFilterBar:ControlConfiguration>
            </smartFilterBar:controlConfiguration>
        </smartFilterBar:SmartFilterBar>
        <Tree id="classTree" items="{path: 'Tree>/'}" toggleOpenState="onToggleOpenState">
            <CustomTreeItem>
                <FlexBox width="100%" alignItems="Center" justifyContent="SpaceBetween">
                    <items>
                        <Label text="{Tree>text}" wrapping="true"/>
                        <Button icon="sap-icon://display" type="Transparent" press="onItemPress"/>
                    </items>
                </FlexBox>
            </CustomTreeItem>
        </Tree>
    </l:content>
    <l:layoutData>
        <l:SplitterLayoutData size="30%"/>
    </l:layoutData>
</l:SplitPane>
```

Then controls disappear:
[image]

Comment: did you try to put your filterbar and tree just inside the splitpane without the panel? or is the panel needed for some functionality?

Comment: I delete the panel control and filterbar and tree does not appear anymore.

Comment: mhh was worth a try, i had similar problem with flexcolumn layout, but there the parts still are views and i just left away the Page control

Comment: I replaced `Panel` through `Page` and now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SAP UI5 class to achieve this on the control by specifying the class

Depending on your need which is margin or padding you can choose.

sapUiNoContentPadding or sapUiNoMargin

Padding:
https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/c7/1f6df62dae47ca8284310a6f5fc80a/frameset.htm

Margin:
https://help.sap.com/saphelp_uiaddon10/helpdata/en/77/7168ffe8324873973151dae2356d1c/frameset.htm

you can specify in example below

```
<l:SplitPane requiredParentWidth="400" demandPane="true" id="default" class="sapUiNoContentPadding ">
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you, As per the new version(1.56.8) you need to remove the class `sapUiCompFilterBarNonPhone` which is adding the padding to the filter bar. Remove the UI5 generated class and add `sapUiTinyMargin` class to have some margin around the filter bar.

You can achieve using the following code.

```
var oFilterBar = sap.ui.getCore().byId("YourFilterBarId");//Update your filter Bar ID
if (oFilterBar)      
 oFilterBar.removeStyleClass("sapUiCompFilterBarNonPhone").addStyleClass("sapUiTinyMargin");
```